# Read initially unknown number of N lines from file in a nested dictionary and start in next iteration at line N+1

Tags: python

I want to process a text file (line by line). An (initially unknown) number of consecutive lines belong to the same entity (i.e. they carry the same identifier with the line). For example:

```
line1: stuff, stuff2, stuff3, ID1, stuff4, stuff5
line2: stuff, stuff2, stuff3, ID1, stuff4, stuff5    
line3: stuff, stuff2, stuff3, ID1, stuff4, stuff5
line4: stuff, stuff2, stuff3, ID2, stuff4, stuff5
line5: stuff, stuff2, stuff3, ID2, stuff4, stuff5
...
```

In this dummy lines 1-3 belong to the entity ID1 and lines 4-5 to ID2. I want to read each of these lines as a dictionary and then want to nest them into a dictionary containing all the dictionaries of IDX (e.g. a dictionary ID1 with 3 nested dictionary of lines 1-3, respectively).

More specifically I would like to define a function that:

1. opens the file
2. reads all (but only) the lines of entity ID1 into individual dictionaries
3. returns the dictionary which carries the nested dictionaries of the ID1 lines

I want to be able to call the function some time later again to read in the next dictionary of all the lines of the following identifier (ID2) and later ID3 etc. One of the problems I am having is that I need to test in every line whether my current line is still carrying the ID of interest or already a new one. If it is a new one, I sure can stop and return the dictionary but in the next round (say, ID2) the first line of ID2 has then already been read and I thus seem to lose that line.

In other words: I would like to somehow reset the counter in the function once it encounters a line with new ID so that in the next iteration this first line with the new ID is not lost.

This seems such a straightforward task but I cannot figure out a way to do that elegantly. I currently pass some "memory"-flags/variables between functions in order to keep track of whether the first line of a new ID was already read in a previous iteration. That is quite bulky and error prone.

Thanks for reading... any ideas/hints are highly appreciated. If some points are unclear please ask.

Here is my "solution". It seems to work in the sense that it prints the dictionary correctly (although I am sure there is a more elegant way to do that). 
I also forgot to mention that the textfile is very large and I hence want to process it ID by ID instead of reading the whole file into memory.

```
with open(infile, "r") as f:
    newIDLine = None
    for line in f:
        if not line:
            break
        # the following function returns the ID
        ID = get_ID_from_line(line)
        counter = 1
        ID_Dic = dict()
        # if first line is completely new (i.e. first line in infile)
        if newIDLine is None:
            currID = ID
            # the following function returns the line as a dic
            ID_Dic[counter] = process_line(line)
        # if first line of new ID was already read in
        # the previous "while" iteration (see below).
        if newIDLine is not None:
            # if the current "line" is of the same ID then the
            # previous one: put previous and current line in
            # the same dic and start the while loop.
            if ID == oldID:
                ID_Dic[counter] = process_line(newIDLine)
                counter += 1
                ID_Dic[counter] = process_line(line)
                currID = ID
        # iterate over the following lines until file end or
        # new ID starts. In the latter case: keep the info in
        # objects newIDline and oldID
        while True:
            newLine = next(f)
            if not newLine:
                break
            ID = get_ID_from_line(newLine)
            if ID == currID:
                counter += 1
                ID_Dic[counter] = process_line(newLine)
            # new ID; save line for the upcomming ID dic
            if not ID == currID:
                newIDLine = newLine
                oldID = ID
                break
    # at this point it would be great to return the Dictionary of
    # the current ID to the calling function but at return to this
    # function continue where I left off.
    print ID_Dic
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Post your code.

Comment: Code now provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this function to lazily return a dict for each id, you should make it a generator function by using yield instead of return. At the end of each id, yield the dict for that id. Then you can iterate over that generator.

To handle the file, write a generator function that iterates over a source unless you send it a value, in which case it returns that value next, then goes back to iterating. (For example, here's a module I wrote to do this for myself: [politer.py](https://github.com/liamliwanagburke/ispeakregex/blob/master/politer.py).)

Then you can solve this problem easily by sending the value "back" if you don't want it:

```
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    polite_f = politer(f)
    current_id = None
    while True:
        id_dict = {}
        for i, line in enumerate(polite_f):
            id = get_id_from_line(line)
            if id != current_id:
                polite_f.send(line)
                break
            else:
                id_dict[i] = process_line(line)
        if current_id is not None:
            yield id_dict
        current_id = id
```

Note that this keeps the state handling abstracted in the generator where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like the stuff I want to do. I was packing your code above into a function foo(infile). To check I called: 'print foo(infile).next()' a couple of times but it never iterates, it just remains at the first ID1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be clear: The it prints the dict for the first ID correctly but then does not move on to the second ID after calling next() on the function.

Comment: This function creates a generator, so calling it repeatedly on the same file will create multiple generators iterating over that file. Instead try `x = foo(infile); print next(x), next(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to keep track of all the `IDX` columns and just add each line's `IDX` column to the appropriate list in  the dictionary, something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

all_lines_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('your_file') as f:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(f)            
  for line_list in csv_reader:
    all_lines_dict[line_list[3]].append(line_list)
```

[Csv reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is part of python standard library, and makes reading csv files easy.  It will read each line as a list of its columns.

This differs from your requirements because each key is not a dictionary of dictionaries but it is a list of the lines that share the `IDX` key.

Comment: Thanks. A question/remark if I may: The file I am reading is very large. This is why I was hoping to only read the lines of a certain ID at a time, process the dictionary, write that to a file and only the proceed to next ID, read all lines of that ID to a dic and so forth. Your example seems to read all lines into the dic before processing it.